# Help each other build a pdf reader-viewer?

Tags: iphone, pdf, sdk

Does anybody that know a little bit about xcoding want to build a pdf reader-viewer together?
I have found a good startingpoint with a reader in a uiwebview. 
What needs to be done is some navigation to step between the pdf pages.
I dont know much xcoding since I build most in uiwebviews, but I know a bit about designing and user navigation. So if you think it would be fun let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you made till now, just upload it to any hosted SVN or GIT sites, and open source the code.

Many people might become interested.